# How to search using getelementid in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I want to search through XML Using GetElementId .

I have an XML file with attributes associated with each element. Elements name may defer but each element will have unique Id.

For example:

```
<root>
<secondRoot>
  <Person UniqueID='A112' Name='Fred'><FeMale>I am Female</FeMale></Person>

  <Person UniqueID='A111'><Male>I am male</Male></Person>
  <Person SSN='A222' Name='Tom'/>
  <Customer id='A111'/>
  <Customer id='A222334444'/>
  <Team members='A222334444 A333445555'/>
  <Random/>
</secondRoot>
</root>
```

In the above XML i have UniqueID attribute associated with several elements. I want to search elements with UniqueID attribute .  Eventhough i tried using following DTD its not sufficient.

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ELEMENT root ANY> 

  <!ATTLIST Person UniqueID ID #REQUIRED>
  ]>
```

The Problem is UniqueID may occur in several elements attribute list. 
I need to avoid a situation which i have to declare every occurances of elements that have UniqueID attribute in DTD.

Can Anyone suggest any idea for that?

Thanks

Comment: "UniqueID may occur in several elements" - then provide a better sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try using LINQ to XML, no need for DTD.

```
// XML data
var xml = "<root><secondRoot><Person UniqueID='A112' Name='Fred'><FeMale>I am Female</FeMale></Person><Person UniqueID='A111'><Male>I am male</Male></Person>  <Person SSN='A222' Name='Tom'/>  <Customer id='A111'/>  <Customer id='A222334444'/>  <Team members='A222334444 A333445555'/>  <Random/></secondRoot></root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Get all nodes that have UniqueID
var nodes = 
    from element in doc.Descendants()
    where element.Attribute("UniqueID") != null
    select element;
```

The `nodes`  list will contain all nodes that have the UniqueID attribute.